# Trouble clipping RGB raster in QGIS: Layer not created

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip

I am brand new to QGIS, and am having trouble clipping a raster to a shape file.

Starting with the three-band red-green-blue (RGB), named 'ortho':

[image]

...I created a shape file to extract the plots that I wanted to, named 'field_boundary':

[image]

I am using the GDAL plugin in order to do this. I went to the top taskbar and chose 'Raster' -> 'Extraction' -> 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer.' The following parameters were used to run the command:

[image]

I am trying to generate a new raster, as the `Clip` tool would do if using ArcGIS. However, I get the following error:

[image]

**What can I do to get this to clip to a new raster?**

Comment: As with any GIS analysis (regardless of the software used), both layers *MUST* be in the same Coordinate Reference System (aka "projection").  Can you confirm that is the case with your raster and vector layers?

Comment: @StuSmith It looks like the CRS for the shape file is **"EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic"**, whereas the orthomosaic CRS lists **"Unknown CRS: BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[GEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984""**. They both say WGS 84, but should I convert the orthomosaic's coordinates to EPSG:4326 perhaps?

Comment: Yes, right click on the ortho layer and define it to EPSG:4326 *if that's what it truly is*, though it is far more common to see orthophotography in projected coordinates it's not impossible to have your ortho in a geographic coordinate reference system. No conversion should be required. QGIS, or more correctly GDALWarp, is getting confused trying to match up WGS84/Geographic to Unknown. If it turns out that your ortho is projected then I suggest you project the clip and not the image so they have the same unit, it's far quicker to project a few vertices than an image.

Comment: I agree with Michael. You need to find out the orthomosaic's CRS.  Perhaps the data provider can supply you with that info, or there's some metadata available listing the CRS.  With that info you could then *define* (not re-project) the ortho's CRS and then, if necessary,  re-project the vector data's CRS to match the ortho.

Comment: All, I reprojected the ortho to WGS 84, and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!